# How to query all fields of the node that is tagged with taxonomy term from a specific vocabulary

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm struggling to find a way to retrieve all the node fields where a specific taxonomy is implemented. I was close to find something with this query :

```
$query = db_query('SELECT fci.field_name
    FROM d7_field_config_instance fci
    LEFT JOIN   (SELECT tv.vid, tv.machine_name
    FROM d7_taxonomy_vocabulary tv
    LEFT JOIN d7_taxonomy_term_data ttd
    ON tv.vid = ttd.vid
    WHERE ttd.tid = 76) AS tax
    ON tax.machine_name LIKE fci.bundle'));
```

But it seems like `machine_name` and `bundle` have different values for a same technology.

The idea is : From a taxonomy id => find taxonomy vid (vocabulary id) => find machine name of the vocabulary => find the bundles where this vocabulary is used.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution**  : Thanks to @Eugis' answer (Accepted answer), I came up with this solution :

```
db_query("SELECT fcf.field_name, fcf.data FROM
          (SELECT fc.field_name, fc.data FROM field_config fc
          WHERE fc.type LIKE 'taxonomy_term_reference') AS fcf
        INNER JOIN field_config_instance fci
          ON fcf.field_name = fci.field_name
          AND fci.bundle LIKE :bundle",
      array(':bundle'=> $bundle));
```

Hope it'll help someone else.

Comment: I edited the title of your question to reflect your goal better. Please correct it if I went in a wrong direction.

Comment: No that is perfect. Thanks for correcting my approximate English ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should check the `field_config` table where `type = 'taxonomy_term_reference'`.
The vocabulary name where the field is referencing to is stored in the `data` column as `BLOB`. you can use the [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unserialize.php) php function to extract the data stored in the `BLOB`. That's because you can't reach it with a single select query.

Try using loops and ifs :)